# Google Map API and Demo

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I want to create a simple application that uses the Google maps API and SQLite database.

Simply I want to create a database that contains a location and text about that location.

I have had a terrible time trying to figure out how to get the Maps API key. Mine has never worked.

Does anyone know of sample code of an app that simply plots points on a map...then maybe allows navigation?

Anything help will be awesome.

Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this tutorial, you can see all common usage of the API : 
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

**Do not forget to generate the API key (explanation at the beginning of the tutorial)!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to go here first:
[Obtaining a Maps API Key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Keep in mind that you'll have to create 2 keys, one for your project in debug mode, and the other for your production app.

Comment: Ah. good point. I was wondering how this might work. I have seen a lot of post about testing teh app in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Link for google maps android v2  :: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Once you install the api, it will also contain sample code , read this link ::
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

Note: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 3rd, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.